# Re-direccionamiento según grupo de usuario Django 2.2.2

Tags: django, login, redirección, django-urls

estoy intentando re direccionar a una "**X**" página, según el grupo al que pertenezca un usuario de la siguiente forma en el fichero **settings.py** :

```py
#Redireccionamiento en caso de contraseña correcta y tipo de usuario
if user.groups.name  == "Doctores":
    LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/doctor/home-doctor/'
elif user.groups.name == "Auxiliares":
    LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/auxiliar/home-auxiliar/'
elif user.is_admin:
    LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/admin/'
```

Cuando pongo el servidor en marcha, aparece el siguiente error:

[image: Error al arrancar el servidor]

Según entiendo, es porque "**user**" no está definido. ***¿Como sería la forma correcta de re-direccionar a distintas páginas, según el grupo al que se pertenece?***

Quedo atento a sus comentarios.

**Extend**

Con el siguiente código logro obtener el grupo al que pertenece cada usuario que se logea, pero quisiera saber si es posible redireccionar a distintas páginas desde el template y como se hace.

```
{% if user.groups.all.0.name == "Doctores" %}
<h2>Pertenece al grupo doctores</h2>
{% elif user.groups.all.0.name == "Auxiliar" %}
<h2>Pertenece al grupo Auxiliar</h2>
{% else %}
<h3>No pertece a ningun grupo</h3>
{% endif %}
```

[image: Resultado tipo de grupo]

Comment: Podrías intentar hacer un decorador para las vistas, y en vez de usar el `login_required` usar uno creado por ti donde puedas validar el usuario que viene de la sesión y determinar a qué url debe ir. O bien crear una página que solo sirva para redireccionar de acuerdo al grupo, y a todos los mandas a esa página, ya que esa validación no puedes hacerla a nivel de configuración

Comment: @GermanAlzate estoy buscando información respecto a lo que me comentas, si tienes algo relacionado te agradecería que me lo facilites.

Comment: @JackNavaRow tienes algo de información sobre como redireccionar correctamente a diferentes páginas según el grupo al que pertenezca?, me sería de gran ayuda.

Comment: @JackNavaRow acabo de agregar informacion en donde me es posible obtener el grupo de usuario al que pertenece y mostrar un mensaje segun su grupo. Sin embargo me gustaría saber la forma de poder redireccionar a una página según su grupo desde un template.

Comment: @JackNavaRow no, tengo solo un login, pero tengo vistas distintas para cada grupo.

Answer (score 1):

Saludos lo que puedes es agregar una función a la cual rediriges luego del login.

En tu settings.py:

```
   from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
   ....
    ..
    LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('miapp:validar_usuario')
```

esa sera la url donde rediriges luego del login, ahora la función sera la que tenga la lógica que deseas algo así:

```
def ValidarUsuario(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
      if request.user.groups.name  == "Doctores":
        return redirect('/doctor/home-doctor/')
      elif request.user.groups.name == "Auxiliares":
        return redirect('/auxiliar/home-auxiliar/')
      elif request.user.is_admin:
        return redirect('/admin/')
    return redirect('login')
```

Recuerda esta función estara en una vista(views.py) de alguna app tuya, debes crear una url que apunte hacia esta funcion e incluir la url en tu settings.py.

Espero te sirva..!!

Comment: No me funciona, puesto que si incluyo el  `reverse_lazy('miapp:validar_usuario')` en **settings.py**, intenta realizar una acción en el archivo de configuración y lo toma como una variable no definida.

Comment: debes importar el " reverse_lazy" ..con "from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy"

Comment: Diego, recuerda que `user.groups` retorna un arreglo o un Queryset iterable, por lo que acceder a `groups.name` y verificar si es igual a `Doctores` por ejemplo, no va a funcionar como se espera. Si quieres puedes guiarte de como lo hace [django-braces](https://github.com/brack3t/django-braces/blob/master/braces/views/_access.py#L309) en sus mixins, pero orientado a un decorador. De esta forma evitas tener que hacer tantas redirecciones

Answer (score 1):

En tu caso yo haría un decorador para las vistas basadas en funciones, o un mixin para las vistas basadas en clases, el problema es que no especificas cual estás usando o si usas ambas, por el momento te intentaré dar una solución con el decorador para vistas basadas en funciones:

Creas un archivo de `decorators.py` puede ser en el root o ya sea en un directorio, o puedes ponerlo en tu archivo de `utils.py` si tienes uno:

```
from functools import wraps
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def custom_login_required(view_func):
    @wraps(view_func)
    def wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = request.user
        LOGIN_URL = '/'
        user_groups = user.groups.values_list("name", flat=True)
        if 'Doctores' in user_groups:
            LOGIN_URL = '/doctor/home-doctor/'
        elif 'Auxiliares' in user_groups:
            LOGIN_URL = '/auxiliar/home-auxiliar/'
        elif user.is_admin:
            LOGIN_URL = '/admin'
        else:
            LOGIN_URL = '/'

        if user.is_authenticated:  # esto puede variar de acuerdo a la versión de django que uses, pero si no funciona usa if user.is_authenticated()
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return redirect(LOGIN_URL)
    return wrapped_view
```

Luego para usarlo solo es necesario que la importes adecuadamente y la uses sobre la ruta así:

```
from .decorators import custom_login_required  # por ejemplo

@custom_login_required
def home_doctor(request):
    ...
```

Si necesitas implementarlo en una *Class based view* me haces un comentario y te ayudo con esa parte