# Redireccionamiento por grupo de usuario Django 2.x

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-urls

Estoy intentando redireccionar usuarios según el grupo al que pertenezcan y no logro concretarlo.

me aparece el siguiente error:
[image: error]

dejo código actual de los diferentes archivos.

**Fichero urls.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect 
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Create your views here.
@login_required
if request.is_authenticated:
    if  request.User.groups.name == "Doctores":
        def homeDoctor(request):
            return render(request,'home_doctor.html')
    elif User.groups == "Auxiliar":
        def homeAuxiliar(request):
            return render(request,'home_auxiliar.html')
```

rutas fichero **settings.py:**

```py
#Redireccionamiento en caso de contraseña correcta y tipo de usuario
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/home_doctor/'


#Redireccionamiento cuando se cierra la sesión
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
```

código del fichero fichero **urls.py:**

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView,LogoutView

urlpatterns = [
    path('home_doctor/', views.homeDoctor, name="home_doctor"),
    path('home_auxiliar/',views.homeAuxiliar, name="home_auxiliar"),
    path('login/',LoginView.as_view() , name="login"),
    path('logout/',LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
]
```

y por último el código del fichero **urls.py** el cual pertenece al proyecto:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include



urlpatterns = [
    #Incluimos las urls de la app core
    path('', include('core.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #Paths de Auth
    path('accounts/', include('registration.urls')),
    #Paths de Auxiliares
    path('auxiliar/',include('auxiliar.urls')),
    #Paths de Doctor
    path('doctor/',include('pacientes.urls')),
]
```

Lo que busco, es que al ingresar el usuario y contraseña en el login, pueda redireccionar a una de las páginas que tengo dentro de la función dependiendo del grupo al que pertenezca el usuario.

quedo atento a sus comentarios.

Comment: Creo que te había hecho una respuesta a esta pregunta y de paso podrías solucionar este error, solo mira [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/274651/15252)

Answer (score 0):

creo que al request falta el enlace con el user. Puedes intentar lo siguiente

```
@login_required
def mi_funcion(request):
   if request.user.is_authenticated:
```

o

```
@login_required
def mi_funcion(request):
   if not request.user.is_anonymous:
```

Este último verifica que si el usuario no es anónimo

Además quizás puedas tener un problema con la forma de acceder al modelo Groups, ya que éste mantiene una relación de "uno a muchos", es decir que un usuario puede pertenecer a varios grupos, por lo que request.user.groups (el user va en minúscula) te traerá una instancia de uno a muchos, lo que te generará un error al explorar el campo name. Para esto te propongo dos alternativas:

1.- Si los usuarios pertenecerán a un grupo, podrías hacer esto:

```
if request.user.groups.filter()[0].name == 'Doctores':
```

o

```
if request.user.groups.filter().first().name == 'Doctores':
```

2.- Si los usuario pudieran pertenece a varios grupos, entonces esto podría resolverlo:

```
 if request.user.groups.filter(name='Doctores').exists():
```

Comment: Hola, al reemplazar el código  aparece el siguiente error:

  `if request.user.is_authenticated:
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: No me habia fijado, el decorator @login_required debe preceder a una función. Vuelve a ver el código de arriba

Comment: Sigue apareciendo otro tipo de error. veré si hay otra forma de hacerlo.